# passing input variable to another gui inside a gui

Tags: matlab

I have main gui with two other sub gui, i understood how to get a output variable from one sub gui to main gui.

This pushbutton function is in main gui

```
 function pb_main_moisture_content_calc_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  % hObject    handle to pb_main_moisture_content_calc (see GCBO)
  % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
  % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

   m_sc = sub_MoistureContent_Calculator();
```

This pushbutton function is in sub1 gui:

```
   function pb_sub1_update_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pb_sub1_update (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    m_sc = getappdata(handles.sub_Moist_Calc, 'appdata_m_sc');
    handles.output = m_sc;
    guidata(hObject,handles);
    uiresume(gcf);
```

But i want this m_sc variable in to a another sub gui, what do i need to do for this to happen?

Answer (score 2):

You could use appdata to share data between the two GUI's.

One way to achieve this:
Register both GUI's and their relation in appdata for MATLAB (handle == 0).